# Compare DateTime in Fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I want to compare a dateTime Object with the today date.

This is my date Object

```
<f:format.date format="d.m.Y - H:i:s">{article.validFrom}</f:format.date>
```

I want to make a condition, if the date Object is bigger than the current day. I will do something.

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Convert the date to an unix timestamp using `format="U"` and compare them. You need to add a variable which contains the current date.

In your controller add

```php
$this->view->assign('date_now', new DateTime());
// or for TYPO3 >= 6.2
$this->view->assign('date_now', new \DateTime());
```

then in your template use following

```xml
<f:if condition="{f:format.date(date: article.validFrom, format: 'U')} > {f:format.date(date: date_now, format: 'U')}">
    Date is valid
</f:if>
```

---

**EDIT:**
The other way (and I think is the better way) is to add a new method to your model which checks this. Example:

Classes/Domain/Model/Article.php

```php
class Article extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {

    /**
      * @return boolean
      */
    public function getDateIsValid() {
        return ($this->getValidFrom() > new DateTime());
    }

}
```

then you can simply use

```xml
<f:if condition="{article.dateIsValid}"></f:if>
```

Comment: For the first way: is there something else needed to make date_now appear in the view/template? I'm adding it, but nothing is output. Does date_now need to be defined in the/a model somehow?

Comment: Got it! it works with the list action, but not with the show action. Why. Because there is Templates/Show.html, which mostly only calls Partials/Items/Properties.html - so the variable has to be passed along to properties as well.

Comment: PS: new DateTime() produced an error in the controller with TYPO3 6.2

Comment: In TYPO3 6.2, it's \DateTime(). I'm adding that above